# How can I move everything from my MacBook Pro Retina mid 2012 to a new MacBook Pro without reinstalling everything

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, restore, migration

I have a MacBook Pro 15 Retina (mid 2012) that has my working environment set up - Parallels Desktop with Windows machine, some software for Mac and Windows.

I am to start using a new MacBook Pro Retina 13 (2013) tommorow.

Is there a backup and restore procedure for Mac I can use to have a reinstall everything-free migration from one machine to another?

My MacBook Pro is Running the latest OS X Mavericks 10.9.3.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways to do this, you have partially answered your own question... Most "hassle free" way would be using Migration Assistant on both Macs.

The procedure is described with a step by step procedure below:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5872

I would suggest you avoid the Wi-Fi option altogether, due to a lot lower speeds than a thunderbolt cable, but it can be used if you have no thunderbolt cable, or no external HDD that you can create a Time Machine backup on.